# Is it possible to programmatically create BackgroundWorkers?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm trying to let user choose amount of threads that can be used to perform a task by using background workers.

Is there any way to automatically create up to 250 background workers?

Comment: Yes. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Could you give us more context of your issue? What do you mean by automatically? Do you mean not write any code to create the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @Default, so user can chose 1-250 amount of threads. Therefore I need to generate up to 250 workers?

Comment: Goodness. Is your app meant for fellow programmers? Or average Joe?

Comment: You can create a new BackgroundWorker in a for loop, just like any other object. The better question is why on earth you would want to do this? Give is some more info and we might be able to suggest an improved method. What is it that the BackgroundWorker is supposed to do?

Comment: @KingCronus, I try to figure out how to make a port scanner that would scan range of ports on single host. I want to use multiple threads to make scanning faster.

Comment: @HelpNeeder - Do you have code to determine how ports should be scanned in each thread?  If you don't have that logic, then what you want us to provide, is sort of pointless.

Comment: Are you sure that 250 threads is going to provide any kind of improvement in processing?  Your CPU is limited to the number of available cores, and the most likely bottleneck will be your network interface.  Increasing the number of threads so drastically is likely to result in slower performance, not faster!

Comment: @Dan Puzey, To deal better with timeouts and slow connection rates. 250 might be a bit extreme, but nevertheless could be useful.

Comment: Hence using TaskScheduler. Let that worry about how many threads, rather than your end-user.

Comment: You'd be best served with tasks, rather than threads. Usually, when a program allows the user to define the number of threads to run, it's so the user can **limit** the number of threads, not make them skyrocket. Creating, switching and destroying threads is a very costly process. A thread also requires quite an amount of memory. Tasks are a lot cheaper in this regard and are going to be assigned to already existing threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you would be better off using C# Tasks.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx

The example even shows an example of 500 tasks.

That way you can simply set the `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` in order to provide the functionality you are looking for.

BackgroundWorkers aren't good for your task, C# Tasks are going to be better. The TaskScheduler is going to be far more efficient.

Comment: Well, I used regular Threads instead, thanks though. And this is because I couldn't make tasks doing the cast at once, instead, it did one task at a time and I wasn't sure how to prevent it.